# ¿Cuál es la palabra más adecuada para referirse a un olor o fragancia agradable?

Tags: selección-de-palabras, sinónimos, poesía

Estuve componiendo algunos poemas. Sin embargo, cuando intento completar el siguiente poema:

> Su _________ de mujer,
>
> Inquietó todo mi ser,
>
> Tanto, que no pude creer.
>
> Lo fácil que es en el amor caer.

Encuentro difícil seleccionar una de las siguientes palabras:

- Olor
- Aroma
- Fragancia

Estoy buscando una explicación sobre ¿cuál es la palabra más adecuada para referirse a un olor o fragancia agradable?

*Nota: las respuestas no tienen porqué estar limitadas a la composición de poemas.*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yo descartaría `olor`, porque este puede ser tanto bueno como malo. `Aroma` y `fragancia` tienen ambas por el contrario connotaciones sólo positivas de acuerdo al DRAE:

[Aroma](http://buscon.rae.es/drae/srv/search?id=rIxPEzMduDXX2sEdCflQ)

> Perfume, olor muy agradable.

[Fragancia](http://buscon.rae.es/drae/srv/search?val=fragancia)

> Olor suave y delicioso.

En la definición de `aroma` encontramos **perfume** que también cualifica bastante bien.

Creo que

> Su **perfume** de mujer,

queda bastante bien, pero tiene cierta connotación de "artificial". Es decir, ella se ha puesto perfume (colonia), en lugar de "ella huele bien de manera natural". Para esta última yo usaría *fragancia* porque me parece más evocativa que *aroma*.

Podría usar también [**Esencia**](http://lema.rae.es/drae2001/srv/search?id=2nI88P2ybDXX2ayYIKxj)

> 3. f. Extracto líquido concentrado de una sustancia generalmente aromática.
> 4. f. Perfume líquido con gran concentración de la sustancia o sustancias aromáticas.

Si no recuerdo mal "Esencia de mujer" era el título (por lo menos español) de una película.

Comment: +1 Por `esencia`.

Comment: @Diego, efectivamente: https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scent_of_a_Woman No sé si eso podría «distraer» al lector cinéfilo, ya que es bastante conocida.

Answer (score 2):

Yo te recomiendo una palabra la cual se utiliza mucho en español para referirse al olor producido por una persona, aunque también tiene otro significado. Pienso que sería correcta para esa definición la palabra "HUMOR", la cual se podría decir que es sinónimo de "olor corporal".

Comment: Interesante.  Yo nunca había oído esto, pero encontré este uso, como tú dices, en el internet, por ejemplo, "Los olores corporales indican problemas de salud. Cada persona tiene un humor muy particular, sin embargo, gracias a estos se puede saber si se tiene alguna enfermedad. Se sabe que si el olor es similar al cloro, indica malestares renales o hepáticos. Cuando es afrutado tiene relación a la diabetes."

Answer (score 0):

A mi parecer es aroma, ya que intuye que nace de la mujer esencialmente del que un hombre suele percibir por atracción de sexo.  En caso de un animal sería olor, en caso de una mujer: aroma.

Answer (score 0):

"Olor" suena animal, mundano como el olor corporal y del aliento, por ejemplo el kareishū.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_person_smell

"Fragancia" suena a pefume que envuelve, tiene connotación de fantasía sexual.

"Aroma" a "aromarizante", a accesorio para vehículos o a pastillas desodorantes para inodoro para al ambiente.

"Esencia" a algo del "alma".